# How to delete custom fields permanently through metadata api

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I'm trying to delete custom fields and create new fields on the upload of a csv file with the header names of the csv but the fields are not getting permanently deleted and i have to erase them manually.Is there any way that i can delete the fields permanently programmatically using Apex??

i just mentioned the piece of code I am using to delete fields and i get the fields by using schema methods.

```
MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort(); 
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId(); 
String[] newStringDeletedFields = new String[] { stringDeletedFields[k] }; 
List<MetadataService.DeleteResult> results = 
    service.deleteMetadata('CustomField', newStringDeletedFields);
```

Comment: Using **ANT** and **SFDC Migration tool** you can achieve this.

Comment: could you please provide some links where i can refer about this as i have no idea about SFDC Migration tool

Comment: @RohitMourya: I am not sure if ANT deletes the field permanently, it puts it in the recycle bin.

Comment: @Anu: can you please be more specific about your question by adding details like how you are deleting and adding fields?

Comment: @Mahmood i just mentioned the piece of code I am using to delete fields and i get the fields by using schema methods

MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
                    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();  
                    String[] newStringDeletedFields = new String[]{stringDeletedFields[k]};
                        
List<MetadataService.DeleteResult> results = service.deleteMetadata('CustomField', newStringDeletedFields);   
}   
}

Comment: @Anu can you please edit your post and make this code part of your question. So others who see your question would be able to better understand it and help you quickly.

Comment: @Mahmood  edited thankyou :)

Comment: @Anu, I do not think you can 'Hard' delete a custom field using metadataAPI. You could 'Soft' delete the fields though, which means the fields will be there in the Recycle bin. To hard delete, you could use ANT script. It is easy to use. Find this link that might be of help:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm